# GitHub: When should I make a Fork?

Tags: git, github

I'm using a project on GitHub as an library in my iOS App. At the moment, I do not have anything to add to the [master project](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD.git). Should I just clone the master repository down to my workspace or just I still create a Fork? When I create a Fork, is will appear in `GitHub for Mac` which makes is easier for me to check for updates. How should I handle a situation like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - to fork or not to fork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343694/git-to-fork-or-not-to-fork)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clone it. GitHub for Mac is capable of tracking any git project; you can always fork the project later.